# Protecting Routes with Middleware in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I have a project that it has two sections "admin" and "student".

I want to make a middleware that if a user who authenticated if his role was 1 automatically redirect it to admin panel and if his role was 2 automatically redirect it to student panel.
i made this middleware but when im test it i have "Too Many Rediredcts" error :

[image]

**My Middleware Code :**

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role === 1){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect()->route('front.index');
    }
```

**My Routes :**

[image]

How can i solve this?

Comment: [edit] and post your code, instead of picture

Comment: shouldn't the else statement redirect to `admin.index` route instead? Also, did you add your middleware into `App\Http\Kernel.php`'s $routeMiddleware array?

Comment: yes i added middleware to Kernel.php in $routeMiddleware array. I want to if user role was 1 redirects to admin.index and if user role was 2 redirects to front.index

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and resolve it by using redirection with Url-like redirect('/admin/login'). Check and try the below code in your Laravel app.

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role === 1){
    return $next($request);
}else{
    return redirect('/admin/login')->withErrors(['Access Denied']);
}
```

OR

```
if (auth()->check() && auth()->user()->role === 1){
        return $next($request);
    }else{
        return redirect()->to('/admin/login')->withErrors(['Access Denied']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your middleware, it's hard to identify the problem, but the rest of your code looks fine. Try changing your your middleware to something like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, string $roleName)
{
    if (Auth::user()->isRole($roleName)) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    abort(403);
}
```

We're passing a role into the middleware from the route, in your case you might pass admin. So any of your admin routes will now look like this:

```
Route::middleware('checkRole:admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', [BackController::class 'index'])->name('admin.index')
});
```

You are now passing a string variable to your middleware `$roleName`

Of course you'll also need to implement the `isRole()` method on your `User.php` Model. This will be something like:

```
 /**
 * @return HasOne
 */
public function role(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class, 'id', 'role_id');
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isRole($roleName): bool
{
    $role = $this->role()->first();
    if(!is_null($role) && $role->name == $roleName) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've made an assumption that you have a `role_id` column on your `User.php` Model, that you have a `Role.php` Model with `name` column which will match `admin` etc and you also have `$routeMiddleware` in `Kernel.php` something similar to `'checkRole' => checkRole::class,`

Tested and working in Laravel 6/Laravel 8

If you wanted to test auth, I would update your route middleware to take an array, perhaps similar to:

`['auth', 'checkRole:admin']`

Where I have `abort(403)` you'll need a map of routes to roles, example: if you are an admin `return redirect()->route('admin.index')`